# How to globally put subscripts in math-mode in upright font using amsmath?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, amsmath

I'm often apply the subscript environment in math-mode to assign e.g. materials to material properties, `$\eta_{oil}$`, `$\lambda_{air}$`, etc. Not very mathematical but hey, I'm an engineer ;-)

I'm applying the amsmath package, so this puts the subscript in italics as most other letters. I don't want that. Of course there are numerous ways to change this locally 
(`$\eta_{\mathrm{oil}}$` feels most appropriate), but this is cumbersome.

So is there a nice, slick TeXy way to address this? Possibly applying anything like `\DeclareMathSomething{}{}{}{}`?

I'd like to do that globally since 99% of my usage of `$_{}$` is not related to variables. And in the very few situations the subscript is an variable, I still could use `$_{\mathnormal{}}$`...

I'm grateful for all suggestions.

Answer (score 13):

I'd use a different character for this. Here I use `!` for upright subscripts (and define `\exclam` if you need `!` in math mode as itself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begingroup\lccode`~=`!
\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}#1{_{\mathrm{#1}}}
\mathchardef\exclam=\mathcode`!
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`!=\string"8000 }

\begin{document}
$a_{x}+b!{eff}=n\exclam$
\end{document}
```

[image]

When a character is given `\mathcode` 32768 (`"8000` is the hexadecimal for it and `\string` is a precaution against `babel` doing strange things) it has a peculiar behavior. It performs normally in text mode, but when found in math mode it becomes like a macro, more precisely like an active character.

A definition of `!` as active character must be present; the trick

```
\begingroup\lccode`~=`!
\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}#1{_{\mathrm{#1}}}
```

is the same as

```
{\catcode`!=\active \gdef!#1{_{\mathrm{#1}}}
```

but I prefer avoiding `\gdef` whenever it's possible. So when TeX finds `!` in math mode it looks for an argument and transforms it into `_{\mathrm{<argument>}}`, which is precisely what you're after.

Finally, `` \mathchardef\exclam=\mathcode`! `` defines `\exclam` to produce the same that would be produced by `!` in math mode if we hadn't redefined it.

---

If you don't plan using only ASCII letters in your subscripts, then you should change `\mathrm` into `\textnormal`, so also accented letters are allowed (and spaces are respected).

Comment: Could you explain what the single commands do?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `\textup` instead of `\mathrm`, then national chars are allowed, for example `R_{\textup{sø}}` in Danish might stand for the radius of a (circular) lake. `ø` is not allowed in `\mathrm`.

Comment: @daleif Perhaps, it depends on what the OP is after.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a beautiful way to handle that issue. Again, great help, thank you so much.

Comment: @egreg, it is more for the archives. Such that others coming by this answer don't get nasty surprises.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use something like the following:

```
\newcommand{\mstr}[1]   {\ensuremath{\mathit{#1}}}
\newcommand{\subs}[2]   {#1\mstr{_#2}}
```

Of course, you could e.g. change `\mathit` to `\mathrm`. Then use it like

```
\subs{x}{y}
```