# Non-italic (roman) subscripts in math mode

Tags: math-mode, subscripts

Is there a way to set indices (subscripts) to non-italic globally? I'm aware of the case by case

```
X_{\text{text goes here}}
```

But I'm having to change that across a whole document is becoming a pain.

Comment: The following is not an answer but a remark. With `\text` the font will change with the surrounding text, so it'll e.g. be italic inside a theorem environment. This is probably undesirable, so I would recommend using `\textnormal` instead.

Comment: It is possible to overload `_` to do this, but it might break things. Might defining `\newcommand*\subtxt[1]{_{\textnormal{#1}}}` and doing a search-and-replace for `_` → `\subtxt ` be a good alternative?

Comment: see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228606/2388

Comment: @Circumscribe thanks! I'll give that a try!

Comment: @AndyGrey: make sure to include a space in `\subtxt ` (at the end) if your document contains things like `X_a` without `{}`.

Comment: Are you able and willing to compile your documents under LuaLaTeX (if you don't already do so)?

Comment: Please also confirm that really all letters in subscript positions should be rendered in upright ("roman") letters. E.g., should the letters `i` and `j` in `x_i` and `y_j` be typeset using upright letters? Or should only groups of 2 or more, or 3 or more, letters in subscript positions be typeset using roman characters?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible to overload `_` to set all subscripts in roman type, but that seems like a bad idea since it might break something unexpected.

You may instead want to consider defining a macro that produces an upright subscript. I've defined such a macro (`\subtxt`) below.
Since it seems unlikely that you'll need underscores in math mode, I've also redefined `\_` to expand to `\subtxt` whenever it is used in math mode (and to produce an underscore otherwise, like normal).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} %% <- necessary for correct scaling of subscripts

\begin{document}

\newcommand*\subtxt[1]{_{\textnormal{#1}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand\_{\ifmmode\expandafter\subtxt\else\textunderscore\fi}

\[
    X_i + X\subtxt{i} + X\_i + X\_{text goes here}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

#### Notes:

- I'm using `\textnormal` instead of `\text` because the font of subscripts created with the latter command changes based on the surrounding text. You for instance probably wouldn't want all of your subscripts inside theorem environments to be in italics. See e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98407/156366) for more info.
- I'm using `\DeclareRobustCommand` to redefine `\_` because the original version of this macro is also defined like that. It isn't too important, but more information can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/156366).

Unless you're using underscores for some other purpose in your document, you can now do a search-and-replace to change every `_` into `\_`.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\sbox0{$$}

\scriptfont1=\scriptfont0


$X_{abc}+y_{max}$


\end{document}
```

Note this affects all math uses of the script size font not just subscripts.

Comment: Would that work for equation, align and other environments?

Comment: @AndyGrey yes..

Comment: (Most notably affected are superscripts and the numerator/denominator of inline fractions.)

Comment: @Circumscribe yes

Comment: @Circumscribe also stick to a-z, don't try `\alpha\beta\gamma....`

Comment: What kind of sorcery is `\sbox0{$$}` for? Just loading the math fonts?

Comment: @Werner latex delays finalizing the math setup until the first use of math at each font size, so that you can switch math fonts. actually for basic math at `\normalsize` it probably makes no difference as things are pre-loaded, but it's a good habit to make sure...

Comment: `$x_{max}$ works\footnote{But $X_{max}$ doesn't} and what about $x_{max}$?`

Comment: I couldn't get this to work consistantly. It worked in some places but not in others. I'm also using sfmath which broke it.

Comment: @AndyGrey yes it's really a sketch to show an approach, because I made a one-line answer just switching the tex-primitive  font setting without updating teh highr level latex font tables, there is a chance that latex switches it back (eg a font size changes)  it wouldn't take a _lot_ more code to instead declare this roman script font through the latex font declarations, but  again if a package like sfmath is re-setting teh same fonts the timing might be package-specific.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest to use a different character for those subscripts. One way could be to use `?` that's very rarely used in math mode. Another uses `↓` (maybe you can find a way to type it easily).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newunicodechar} % for using ↓

% the main command
\newcommand{\uprightsubscript}[1]{_{\textnormal{#1}}}

% this sets up the use of ?
\begingroup\lccode`~=`?\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\uprightsubscript
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`?="8000 }

% this sets up the use of ↓
\newunicodechar{↓}{\uprightsubscript}

\textheight=2cm % just for making a smaller picture

\begin{document}

$x?{max}$ works\footnote{Also here $x?{max}$} and again $x?{max}$?

$x↓{max}$ works\footnote{Also here $x↓{max}$} and again $x↓{max}$?

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. Subscripts enclosed by curly braces are typeset with upright ("roman") letters, as long as there's no space between the `_` (underscore) character and the material enclosed in curly braces. If a subscript term is not enclosed in curly braces, e.g., `$x_i$`, it's not processed by the Lua code.

If, for some reason, you do *not* want to the Lua function to operate on a subscript term encased in curly braces, just make sure that there are one or more spaces between `_` and the subscript term. An obvious reason for wanting to suspend operation of the Lua function would be the fact that the subscript term contains math material which should be processed in math mode.

To activate operations, issue the instruction `\upsubOn`. To terminate them completely, execute `\upsubOff`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,unicode-math}
\usepackage{luacode}
%% Lua-side code:
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function sub_up ( s )
  return ( s:gsub ( "_(%b{})" , "_{\\textnormal%1}" ) )
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}
%% LaTeX-side code:
\newcommand\upsubOn{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback( 
    "process_input_buffer" , sub_up , "subup" )}}
\newcommand\upsubOff{\directlua{luatexbase.remove_from_callback( 
    "process_input_buffer" , "subup" )}}
\AtBeginDocument{\upsubOn}  % activate the Lua function by default

\begin{document}
$X_{text goes here}$\quad $x_ {ab cd}$\quad $x_ {i_j},x_k^u$

\upsubOff
$X_{text goes here}$\quad $x_ {ab cd}$\quad $x_ {i_j},x_k^u$
\end{document}
```