# Italics for subscripts (indexes) or use roman (upright)?

Tags: subscripts, italic, roman

How do you place the indices of e.g. resistors in an electrical network?
For $R_1$, $R_2$ (resistor values): here the 1 and 2 are up (roman).
So should you place $R_A$ or place R_\text{A}. In most books i see R_\text{A}, but i have the impression most books always have the indices up, but I also saw others.
I currently put all the subscripts in non-italics (like in the books), but it does create a lot of typing the \text{}
Is there a workaround, since default most indices are up and not in italics...

Comment: It's probably a matter of taste; see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33120/should-subscripts-in-math-mode-be-upright?rq=1) for more discussion. I usually use whatever the math mode is doing, like `$R_A$`, out of lazyness.

Comment: You could define: `\newcommand*{\sub}[1]{_{\textnormal{#1}}}` to use `R_\sub{A}`. And if you later prefer, e.g. `\mathrm` or `\textup` or even `\text` you can change the definition of `\sub`.

Comment: [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/466411/277964) you can not only find how to make all subscripts in up font, but also how to define additional commands or actives (e.g. `↓` as replacement of `_` but with up font).

Comment: `\text` does not ensure upright, it will produce italic in italic regions, also `_\text{...}` should be `_{\text{....}}`  , `_{\mathrm{A}}` would guarantee upright A