Automatically typeset subscripts upright - how to make it compatible with greek letters?
I am looking for a way to typeset subscripts (that may contain greek letters and umlauts) upright, as a default, when using math-mode.
Upright subscripts as a default have been asked for before, and solutions have been found. However these do not work when including greek letters in a subscript:

math mode - subscripts in upright font by default (a solution that works with umlauts has been shared)

Typeset subscript material automatically in upright font shape (this was the basis to the solution in thread 1, but was not compatible with umlauts - and I think greek letters neither)


The first thread I mentioned also references multiple other similar questions, but none of them adress the issue of greek letters.
Edit: Solution in posting 2 (which Mico pointed to and elaborated on) works with greek letters and umlauts - with some remaining caveats however:

Greek letters are typeset larger, than expected (compare lines 1 and 2 in the example below)
Whitespaces inside the subscript are not ignored anymore (see 3rd line in example below - minor issue, just wanted to point it out)
I cannot find a way to mix upright and math-mode inside a single subscript, that does not result in an error. Line 4 of example below is the desired output, which I get using $a_{1,\sigma,$n$}$. It throws an error though:


unclosed open group { found at $ unclosed open group { found at $
unexpected $ after open group {



Welcome to TeX.SE.


However these [earlier solutions] do not work when including greek letters in a subscript

The second posting you've cross-referenced contains a LuaLaTeX-based solution [shameless self-citation alert!] that works just fine with Greek letters, as long as the fontspec package is loaded and a suitable text font, i.e., a text font that provides the required greek glyphs and glyphs with umlauts, is employed, presumably via a \setmainfont directive.
The key input assumptions are (a) that the subscript term is encased in curly braces and (b) that there's no whitespace between the _ subscript initiator and the material encased in curly braces. To wit, in the following example, the letter t in both $R_t$ and $R_ {t}$ is rendered in math mode -- since the examples fail either test (a) or test (b) -- while the t in $R_{t} is rendered in text mode.

% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}  
\setmainfont{EB Garamond} % choose a suitable text font

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}

function up_subs ( buff )
    return ( unicode.utf8.gsub ( buff , "_(%b{})" , "_{\\textnormal%1}" ) )
end

\end{luacode}

\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback(
    "process_input_buffer", up_subs, "up_subs")}}
    
\begin{document}

$R_t$ $R_{t}$ $R _ {t}$ $R_{ßöÖαω}$ 

\end{document}


Using this solution I referenced earlier with LuaLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX works fine with greek letters (pdfLaTeX will simply not generate a pdf at all).
I find it more user-friendly, than Mico's Lua-based above, because

one can still use f.e. $a_s$ without curly brackets, less confusing for collaborators, because whitespace or brackets don't change the behaviour
it includes toggles to switch the default between upright and non-upright subscripts

Output of the code below:

 % !TEX TS-program = lualatex
    \documentclass{scrartcl}   
    
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    
    % typesetting indexes upright by default (source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/496613)
    \def\subinrm#1{\sb{\textnormal{#1}}}
    {\catcode`\_=13 \global\let_=\subinrm}
    \mathcode`_="8000
    \def\upsubscripts{\catcode`\_=12 } \def\normalsubscripts{\catcode`\_=8 }
    % the toggle for upright subscripts
    \upsubscripts
    % the toggle for italic subscripts
    %\normalsubscripts
    
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l|l|l}
             \verb|$a_s$| & $a_s$ & new default: upright subscripts\\
             \verb|$a_{s,\sigma,ö}$| & $a_{s,\sigma,ö}$ & example with umlauts and greek\\
             \verb|$a_{s,\sigma,n}$| & $a_{s,\sigma, ö}$ & whitespaces inside the subscript are not ignored\\
             \verb|$a_{s,\sigma,\textit{n}}$| & $a_{s,\sigma,\textit{n}}$ & mixing upright and non-upright via \verb|\textit{}|\\
            \verb|$a_{s,\sigma,\textit{n}}$| & $a_{s,\sigma,{$n$}}$ & mixing upright and non-upright via \verb|\textit{}|\\
            \verb|$a_{s,{$\sigma,n$}}$| & $a_{s,{$\sigma,n$}}$ & mixing upright and non-upright via explicit math-mode
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    
    
    \end{document}

The only annoyance left for me is, that f.e. the upright sigma looks bigger than the non-upright. But that is a separate issue, I suppose.
